# Getting error in cryptobot smart contract. [What fix is required ?? ]

Tags: smartpy, python

```
import smartpy as sp
# TODO: Code needs to be fixed.
class Cryptobot(sp.Contract):

    def __init__(self, manager_address, life_state, initial_mutez, market_address):
        
        self.init(
            bot_manager = manager_address,
            name = "terminator",
            is_alive = life_state,
            plasma_bullet_count = 5,

            record_alien_kills = {
                "simple_alien": sp.nat(0), 
                "boss_alien": sp.nat(0), 
            },
            mutez_points = sp.mutez(initial_mutez),
            market_address = market_address,
            active_powerup = sp.record(power = "", duration = 0)
        )

    @sp.entry_point
    def shoot_alien(self, alien_type):
        
        sp.verify(
            self.data.bot_manager == sp.sender, 
            message = "Error: non manager call"
        )

        sp.if self.data.plasma_bullet_count >= 1:
            self.data.plasma_bullet_count -= 1
            self.data.record_alien_kills[alien_type] += 1
        sp.else:
            sp.failwith("Error: you ran out of bullets! Please buy more!")
            
    @sp.entry_point
    def buy_powerup(self, powerup):
        
        # modify data_type to also hold another variable called cryptobot_address.
        # cryptobot_address is of type `sp.TContract` which accepts a record that has the same variables as `active_powerup`.
        data_type = sp.TRecord(powerup = sp.TString, cryptobot_contract = sp.TContract(sp.TRecord(power = sp.TString, duration = sp.TIntOrNat)))
            
        market_contract = sp.contract(data_type, self.data.market_address).open_some()
        self.data.mutez_points -= sp.mutez(3000)
        
        # define self_contract -
        # 1. Accepts a record with two variables - power(string), duration(nat)
        # 2. Points to the Cryptobot( use sp.to_address() ) 
        # 3. Specifies receive_powerup entry point
        
        self_contract = sp.contract(sp.TRecord(power = sp.TString, duration = sp.TNat), sp.to_address(sp.self), "receive_powerup").open_some()
        # modify data_to_be_sent to also hold cryptobot_contract which is assigned self_contract
        data_to_be_sent = sp.record(powerup = powerup, cryptobot_contract = self_contract)
        sp.transfer(data_to_be_sent, sp.mutez(0), market_contract)
        
    
    @sp.entry_point
    def receive_powerup(self, powerup):
        # set active_powerup as the powerup being accepted as a parameter
        self.data.active_powerup.power = powerup.power
        self.data.active_powerup.duration = powerup.duration
    



class Market(sp.Contract):

    def __init__(self):
        self.init(
            powerups = [
                sp.record(power = "time_freeze", duration = 3), 
                sp.record(power = "one_shot_kill", duration = 4)
            ]
        )
    
    
    @sp.sub_entry_point
    def find_powerup(self, powerup):
        powerup_to_send = sp.local("powerup_to_send", sp.record(power = "", duration = sp.nat(0)))
        
        sp.for p in self.data.powerups:
            
            sp.if p.power == powerup:
    
                powerup_to_send.value.power = p.power
                powerup_to_send.value.duration = p.duration
        
        sp.result(powerup_to_send.value)
    
    @sp.entry_point
    def send_powerup(self, params):
        # define a variable powerup_to_send the which is equal to the result of `find_powerup`. 
        # remember to pass find_powerup the powerup sent in params.

        powerup_to_send = self.find_powerup(params.powerup)
        # transfer powerup_to_sent with 0 mutez to the cryptobot_contract sent through the params.
        sp.transfer(powerup_to_send, sp.mutez(0), params.cryptobot_contract)
    
@sp.add_test(name = "inter-contract")
def test():
    scenario = sp.test_scenario()
    
    ## Class Invokation
    my_account = sp.test_account("Cryptobot Owner")
    market = Market()
    scenario += market
    
    test_bot =  Cryptobot(manager_address = my_account.address,life_state = True, initial_mutez=5000, market_address = market.address)
    scenario += test_bot
    
    # test our code over here.
    scenario += test_bot.buy_powerup("time_freeze")
    scenario.verify(test_bot.data.mutez_points == sp.mutez(2000))
    scenario.verify(test_bot.data.active_powerup.power == "time_freeze")
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you found an answer before the one I'm giving you.

I fixed 3 things:

```
# Line 41:
data_type = sp.TRecord(powerup = sp.TString, cryptobot_contract = sp.TContract(sp.TRecord(power = sp.TString, duration = sp.TNat)))
# You cannot use sp.TIntOrNat as a valid type. sp.TNat is the valid type in this case.

# Line 43:
market_contract = sp.contract(data_type, self.data.market_address, entry_point = "send_powerup").open_some()
# You forgot the entrypoint name

# Line 51:
self_contract = sp.self_entry_point("receive_powerup")
# The simplest way to obtain your self entry_point is using this command.
```